# Invalid SQL syntax when trying to insert a row to the database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am getting this error: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '12'.`

The error occurs on the `pbkDB.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand)` line.

```
#region Enhancements_Update
private static bool Enhancements_Update(DataRow dr)
{
   bool inserted = false;
   DateTime dt;
   Database pbkDB = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("PbKConnectionString");

   try
   {
      ChargeCode = dr["ChargeCode"].ToString().Trim();
      NcicCode = dr["NcicCode"].ToString().Trim();
      Description = String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["Description"].ToString().Trim()) ? null : dr["Description"].ToString().Trim();
      MachCr = String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["MachCr"].ToString().Trim()) ? null : dr["MachCr"].ToString().Trim();
      EnterUserId = String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["EnterUserId"].ToString().Trim()) ? "KSCONV" : dr["EnterUserId"].ToString().Trim();
      EnterDate = DateTime.TryParse(dr["EnterDate"].ToString(), out dt) ? dt : DateTime.Now;
      UpdateUserId = String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["UpdateUserId"].ToString().Trim()) ? "KSCONV" : dr["UpdateUserId"].ToString().Trim();
      UpdateDate = DateTime.TryParse(dr["UpdateDate"].ToString(), out dt) ? dt : DateTime.Now;
      EnactedDate = DateTime.TryParse(dr["EnactedDate"].ToString(), out dt) ? dt : DateTime.Now;
      if (DateTime.TryParse(dr["RepealedDate"].ToString(), out dt))
         RepealedDate = dt;
      else
         RepealedDate = null;
      UsageType = String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["UsageType"].ToString().Trim()) ? null : dr["UsageType"].ToString().Trim();
      LanguageFile = String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["LanguageFile"].ToString().Trim()) ? null : dr["LanguageFile"].ToString().Trim();
      MachChar = String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["MachCr"].ToString().Trim()) ? null : dr["MachChar"].ToString().Trim();
      NotesOnUse = String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["NotesOnUse"].ToString().Trim()) ? null : dr["NotesOnUse"].ToString().Trim();
      SentenceSeverity = String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["SentenceSeverity"].ToString().Trim()) ? null : dr["SentenceSeverity"].ToString().Trim();

      DbCommand dbCommand = pbkDB.GetSqlStringCommand(string.Format(@"Update tblCtStateChargeNcic set  Description = '{2}',  MachCr = '{3}', EnterUserId = '{4}', EnterDate = {5}, UpdateUserId = '{6}', UpdateDate {7}, EnactedDate {8}, RepealedDate = {9},  UsageType = '{10}', LanguageFile = '{11}', MachChar = '{12}', NotesOnUse = '{13}',                       SentenceSeverity = '{14}' where ChargeCode = '{0}' AND NcicCode = '{1}')", ChargeCode, NcicCode, Description, MachCr, EnterUserId, EnterDate, UpdateUserId,                     UpdateDate, EnactedDate, RepealedDate, UsageType, LanguageFile, MachChar, NotesOnUse, SentenceSeverity));

      // error occurs here!
      pbkDB.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
      inserted = true;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
   }
   return inserted;
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Print out the full sql command so that you/we can look at it to see what's wrong with it.

Comment: please don't use `string.format`. use a command with parameters.

Comment: The DbCommand dbCommand = ... is the SQL command. What else are you needing to see?

Comment: @DanielA.White - When I use the pbkDB.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "Code", DbType.String, Code);, I get all kinds of errors.

Comment: @Katherine he's asking for the raw SQL that gets built. you should be able to see it by examining in the debugger.

Comment: Update tblCtStateChargeNcic set  Description = 'Instrument Over 10K',  MachCr = '', EnterUserId = 'Pamow', EnterDate = 8/3/2012 12:00:00 AM, UpdateUserId = 'Pamow', UpdateDate = 8/3/2012 12:00:00 AM, EnactedDate = 1/2/2000 12:00:00 AM, RepealedDate = ,  UsageType = '', LanguageFile = 'Instrument Over 10K.doc', MachChar = '', NotesOnUse = '', SentenceSeverity = '' where ChargeCode = '059055' AND NcicCode = 'INSTRUMENT OVER 10K')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are missing the = for UpdateDate {7}, EnactedDate {8}

Comment: With both of those added, I am still getting that same error.

Comment: The issues is that the sql you are generating has some sort of syntax error. The best way to trouble shoot this would be to add a break point and capture what is being returned by pbkDB.GetSqlStringCommand(string.Format ...

Comment: @Katherine - Put a debug stop at `pbkDB.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);` copy the value of `dbCommand` and try running it. The issues you are experiencing is one of the reasons why you should use sql parameters.

Comment: This is what is generated: Update tblCtStateChargeNcic set  Description = 'Instrument Over 10K',  MachCr = '', EnterUserId = 'Pamow', EnterDate = 8/3/2012 12:00:00 AM,  UpdateUserId = 'Pamow', UpdateDate = 8/3/2012 12:00:00 AM, EnactedDate = 1/2/2000 12:00:00 AM, RepealedDate = ,  UsageType = '', LanguageFile = 'Instrument Over 10K.doc', MachChar = '', NotesOnUse = '', SentenceSeverity = '' where ChargeCode = '059055' AND NcicCode = 'INSTRUMENT OVER 10K')

Comment: It's complaining about the dates try adding single quotes around them.

Answer (score 6):

You should use [sql parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) instead of building the string yourself.

Any way, this is your error:

```
UpdateDate {7}, EnactedDate {8}
```

You are missing `=`:

```
UpdateDate = {7}, EnactedDate = {8}
```

Comment: Another +1 for mentioning `SqlParameters`.  I am learning how to use them now, in fact.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that date values must be enclosed in quotes (apostrophes, most likely).

Your string is improperly formatted.

For the record, using strings to create SQL statements is a horrible idea. Use a parameterized query, and add the parameter values with the AddParameterWithValue method. This sort of string splicing is a prime candidate for a SQL injection attack.

Comment: Looks to me as though PJM originally resolved this issue. You should accept his answer, not mine.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
DbCommand dbCommand = pbkDB.GetSqlStringCommand(string.Format
                      (@"Update tblCtStateChargeNcic set  Description = '{2}',  
                      MachCr = '{3}', EnterUserId = '{4}', EnterDate = {5}, 
                      UpdateUserId = '{6}', UpdateDate {7}, EnactedDate {8}, 
                      RepealedDate = {9},  UsageType = '{10}', LanguageFile = '{11}', 
                      MachChar = '{12}', NotesOnUse = '{13}', SentenceSeverity = '{14}'
                      where ChargeCode = '{0}' AND NcicCode = '{1}')", ChargeCode, 
                      NcicCode, Description, MachCr, EnterUserId, EnterDate, 
                      UpdateUserId, UpdateDate, EnactedDate, RepealedDate, 
                      UsageType, LanguageFile, MachChar, NotesOnUse, 
                      SentenceSeverity));
```

To:

```
DbCommand dbCommand = pbkDB.GetSqlStringCommand(string.Format
                      (@"Update tblCtStateChargeNcic set  Description = '{2}',  
                      MachCr = '{3}', EnterUserId = '{4}', EnterDate = {5}, 
                      UpdateUserId = '{6}', UpdateDate = {7}, EnactedDate = {8}, 
                      RepealedDate = {9},  UsageType = '{10}', LanguageFile = '{11}', 
                      MachChar = '{12}', NotesOnUse = '{13}', SentenceSeverity = '{14}'
                      where ChargeCode = '{0}' AND NcicCode = '{1}')", ChargeCode, 
                      NcicCode, Description, MachCr, EnterUserId, EnterDate, 
                      UpdateUserId, UpdateDate, EnactedDate, RepealedDate, 
                      UsageType, LanguageFile, MachChar, NotesOnUse,
                      SentenceSeverity));
```

You left out the '=' for `UpdateDate` and `EnactedDate`.